# strcmp not working

Tags: c, strcmp

I know this may be a totally newbie question (I haven't touched C in a long while), but can someone tell me why this isn't working?

```
printf("Enter command: ");
bzero(buffer,256);
fgets(buffer,255,stdin);

if (strcmp(buffer, "exit") == 0)
    return 0;
```

If I enter "exit" it doesn't enter the if, does it have to do with the length of "buffer"?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want to do this:

`strcmp(buffer, "exit\n")`

That is, when you enter your string and press "enter", the newline becomes a part of `buffer`.

Alternately, use strncmp(), which only compares n characters of the string

Comment: That's good unless the user types a space before, or after, exit.  And don't forget the (probably apocryphal) story of the system that stopped working when Ecuador was added - people had to type Quito for the name of the capital, and the program exited (quit) because only the first 4 letters were compared with 'quit'.  Quite nasty!

Comment: @Jonathan truths! my own suggestion is to ensure that the user is never allowed to input anything into your program.

Answer (score 10):

fgets() is returning the string "exit\n" -- unlike gets(), it preserves newlines.

Comment: ... and "gets" only takes one parameter (buffer in this example). Thanks!

Comment: (Please don't use gets() in public.)

Comment: @Jian, because gets() doesn't protect you against buffer overruns.

Answer (score 6):

As others have said, comparing with `"exit"` is failing because `fgets()` included the newline in the buffer. One of its guarantees is that the buffer will end with a newline, unless the entered line is too long for the buffer, in which case it does not end with a newline. `fgets()` also guarantee that the buffer is nul terminated, so you don't need to zero 256 bytes but only let `fgets()` use 255 to get that guarantee.

The easy answer of comparing to exactly `"exit\n"` required that the user did not accidentally add whitespace before or after the word. That may not matter if you want to force the user to be careful with the **exit** command, but might be a source of user annoyance in general.

Using `strncmp()` potentially allows `"exited"`, `"exit42"`, and more to match where you might not want them. That might work against you, especially if some valid commands are prefix strings of other valid commands.

In the general case, it is often a good idea to separate I/O, tokenization, parsing, and action into their own phases.

Comment: Use: fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp); and don't subtract one (or use 255) because fgets() behaves sanely - you told it how much space there is, and it ensures it uses no more, placing the null terminator in the last available character in the array.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to say... but better said. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Dave. Also you may wish to use strncmp() instead. Then you can set a length for the comparison.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you strip the \n from the end of the string, like this.

```
char buf[256];
int len;
/* get the string, being sure to leave room for a null byte */
if ( fgets(buf,sizeof(buf) - 1) == EOF )
{
  printf("error\n");
  exit(1);
}
/* absolutely always null-terminate, the easy way */
buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';
/* compute the length, and truncate the \n if any */
len = strlen(buf);
while ( len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n' )
{
  buf[len - 1] = '\0';
  --len;
}
```

That way, if you have to compare the inputted string against several constants, you're not having to add the \n to all of them.

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a valid solution though it is not explained.