# strcmp() in program not working

Tags: c, strcmp

I am trying to make a quiz program that reads questions from one file and answers from another file, put them in strings and compare them with `strcmp()`, but for some reason its not working when I put in a correct answer it says its not correct. Any help would be appreciated.

**My Code**

```
int main()
{

    FILE *fpq = fopen("questions.txt", "r");
    FILE *fpa = fopen("answers.txt", "r");

    char question[256];
    char answer[256];
    char user_input[256];

    fgets(question, 256, fpq);
    fgets(answer, 256, fpa);

    puts(question);
    fgets(user_input, 256, stdin);
    if(strcmp(user_input, answer) == 0)
    {
      printf("Good job!\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Nope its:\n");
      puts(answer);
    }
    fclose(fpq);
    fclose(fpa);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you accounting for trailing newlines? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/636009

Comment: The only correct answer is: use a debugger.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` appends a newline `\n` character to the end of the string read into the buffer.
 Refer to this answer which will further explain it [Is trailing newline necessary in fgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26672423/5473170)

Maybe This is the reason your code is not working, please check for the new line at the end of string and remove it.

On Removing newline `\n` character you can refer to [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Also This Question Deals With The Same Issues As Yours [strcmp not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967745/strcmp-not-working?rq=1). It would be good help to you.

And As Paul Oglive Said in the comment learn to use debugger, it will always help.

Comment: Ok I will look up how to use a debugger, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Does The Answer Work For You?

Comment: @emp Also Must see the above mentioned questions and answer, it will really help you a lot, and get a good book like [C Programming a modern approach By K.N King 2nd Edition](https://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Modern-Approach-2nd/dp/0393979504/).

Comment: @emp See The Updated Answer and visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/967745/strcmp-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of `strncmp` to solve your problem. You need to provide the number of characters to be compared.

```
if(strncmp(user_input, answer, strlen(user_input) == 0)
{
  printf("Good job!\n");
}
else
{
  printf("Nope its:\n");
  puts(answer);
}
```

[See-example-here](http://ideone.com/elIXqm)